# Alterar dados em uma planilha através de uma listbox

Tags: vba, excel-vba, textbox, label, microsoft-excel

Tenho um formulário com duas caixas de texto, três botões de comando, uma listbox e algumas labels.

O objetivo do formulário é listar dados que são inseridos no banco de dados (que é a própria planilha do excel).

Como funciona o código:

São inseridos os textos nas 2 texbox e a listbox é alimentada através do rowsource em código.

Funciona quase tudo certo; cadastra o texto, a listbox é alimentada pela BD através do rowsource porém no último estágio que é alterar os dados inseridos o botão não ativa.

Segue o código:

```
'CADASTRAR TEXTO NO LISTBOX

Private Sub Boão_Cadastrar_Click()


If VerificaCampo(Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO01.Text) = False Then
    MsgBox "Informe o texto desejado", vbExclamation, "ERRO"
    Exit Sub

End If

If VerificaCampo(Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO02.Text) = False Then
    MsgBox "Informe o texto desejado", vbExclamation, "ERRO"
    Exit Sub

End If


    Sheets("VALIDAÇÃO").Activate 'ATIVA A PLANILHA CORRESPONDENTE
    Range("E2").Select 'SELECIONA A CÉLULA ESPECIFICADA ENTRE OS PARENTESES

Do 'FAÇA
        If ActiveCell.Value <> Empty Then  'SE O VALOR DA CELULA SELECIONADA FOR DIFERENTE DE VAZIO ENTÃO

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select  'A CELULA ATIVA VAI PARA O CAMINHO INDICADO NOS PARENTESES
        End If                              'FIM DO SE

Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = Empty         'REPETIR ATÉ QUE O VALOR DA CÉLULA ATIVA SEJA IGUAL A VAZIO

    ActiveCell.Value = Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO01 'O VALOR DA CÉLULA ATIVA VAI RECEBER O QUE FOR DIGITADO NA CAIXA DE TEXTO CORRESPONDENTE

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO02.Text 'O MESMO DE CIMA

    MsgBox ("Atualização efetuada com SUCESSO!!") 'MESSAGEM DO SISTEMA

    Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO01.Text = Empty 'LIMPA A CAIXA DE TEXTO
    Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO02.Text = Empty 'LIMPA A CAIXA DE TEXTO

    'ATUALIZA OS DADOS PARA QUE ELES APARECAM NO FORMULÁRIO SEM PRECISAR FECHÁ-LO
    Unload Me
    Userform.Show

End Sub

'CAMPO DE VERIFICAÇÃO

Private Function VerificaCampo(Texto As String) As Boolean

    If Texto = "" Then
    VerificaCampo = False

    Else
    VerificaCampo = True

    End If

End Function

'SELECIONA OS DADOS NA LISTBOX PARA PODER SER FEITA A ALTERAÇÃO EM DADOS

Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO01.Text = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 0) '1ª COLUNA
Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO02.Text = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 1) '2ª COLUNA

End Sub

'BOTÃO QUE ALTERA LEGISLAÇÕES E/OU ARTIGOS

Private Sub Botão_Alterar_Legislações_Artigos_Click()

If VerificaCampo(Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO01.Text) = False Then
    MsgBox "Informe a legislação desejada", vbExclamation, "ERRO"
    Exit Sub

End If

If VerificaCampo(Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO02) = False Then
    MsgBox "Informe o texto desejado", vbExclamation, "ERRO"
    Exit Sub

End If

Dim X As String
Dim Y As String

X = Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO01.Text
ARTIGO = Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO02.Text

Dim LINHA As Integer
LINHA = ListBox1.ListIndex

ListBox1.List(LINHA, 0) = X
ListBox1.List(LINHA, 1) = Y

Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO01 = ""
Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO02 = ""

Me.CAIXA_DE_TEXTO01.SetFocus

End Sub

'LIMPAR TUDO/APAGAR DA PLANILHA

Private Sub Botão_Limpar_Tudo_Click()

[E2:F100000].ClearContents

Unload Me

Userform.Show

End Sub


'POPULAR LISTBOX:

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Ulinha = Range("e1000000").End(xlUp).Row

ListBox1.RowSource = "VALIDAÇÃO!E2:F" & Ulinha

End Sub
```

Comment: Por favor, poderia não escreva o titulo da pergunta em caixa alta. Aproveite e faça um [tour] para aprender mais sobre a comunidade.

Comment: posso sim; desculpe; vou ajeitar.

Comment: Editado. Obrigado; :)